# Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'

Tags: typescript, next.js, module

I've been working on a Next js app and I encountered this error "Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' ". Previously, I had another error "module not found can't resolve 'fs'", but I added "config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };" to my next.config.js and It worked. But now I'm stuck with this error for a couple of hours and I dont know how to fix it. I tried everything I found on Google, but nothing seems to work.

```
next.conig.js

** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // Nextjs has an issue with pdfjs-dist which optionally uses the canvas package
  // for Node.js compatibility. This causes a "Module parse failed" error when
  // building the app. Since pdfjs-dist is only used on client side, we disable
  // the canvas package for webpack
  // https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/16214
  output: 'standalone',
  webpack: (config) => {

    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
    config.resolve.alias.canvas = false;
    config.resolve.alias.encoding = false;
    
    return config;
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

```
tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "paths": {
      "public/*": [
        "../public/*"
      ],
      //"@/*": ["./*"]
      "*": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
  
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```